# what are modern hooking techniques?

Tags: function-hooking, dll-injection, injection, hooking

i was looking at interesting anti malware roles (malware analysis and prevention) and among the required skills they mentioned that "modern hooking techniques" should be well acquainted with. i was wondering what are modern hooking techniques?

can anybody reference me to examples of "modern hooking techniques" and examples of them with code to make understanding easier?

when referring to hooking, malware researchers usually use manual hooking or use frameworks such as pintools/frida?

please elaborate on what you think is modern hooking and please share references or code samples, as it can greatly help me and i believe a lot of other people interested in becoming better at reversing/malware analysis.

thank you for your efforts

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. This question could really use some clarification. For starters, answers to this question are likely going to be opinion-based (not a good fit for this site). Also, what a recruiter/HR person will list as a requirement is - unfortunately - often filtered down from a list they got from the techies. So why don't you ask them which ones they deem modern? Also, hooking refers to so many loosely related techniques that I wonder what exactly could be meant. In the realm of malware I'd also expect some sort of kernel-land hooking techniques to be a requirement.